# Beyond Face Detection-OpenCV

Tags: opengl, opencv, mask, face-recognition

I used the information provided in the OpenCV wiki to make a face detection program which identifies the presence of a face in the Camera feed. The source code that I used was provided in the link given below

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

Now I wanted to take it to another level so that it can actually identify the ears also. Thus I would want to place a mask on the users face which shows the presence of face and also the ears, something like

http://code.google.com/p/ehci/wiki/6dofhead

How to do this without using OpenGL, and using some kind of cascade classifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There HaarCascades available for ears, eyes, nose, mouth, etc. You can use them in the same way as you used Face cascades to detect faces. The cascades are provided with the source.

`OpenCV-version/data/haarcascades`

Comment: So I'll have to make files/find files for ear, nose etc. to be able to identify them?

Comment: No. They are given with package.

Comment: Can you please specify the location of the files?

Comment: in OpenCV folder, OpenCV-2.4.0/data/haarcascades

Answer (score 0):

There is a facedetector example in the OpenCV distribution that shows how to detect the face and some other face features. All you have to do is to send the cascades names to the executable. The cascades are located in the openCV_install/data/cascades/

[Here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/FaceDetection) is the latest tutorial

and [there](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) is a bit older one, compatible with the older cascades.

Comment: Can you please provide a source code example or a link which implements detecting features other than eyes? Thanks.

Comment: Read carefully the tutorial. It clearly explains how to do it.